# Still "Error: USB/Bluetooth Driver" after exclude switches

Tags: python, selenium

Im using the following option while using Chrome and Python:

```
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
```

It works until i use this right after:

```
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
```

The logs give me this message and others:

*[17424:14808:0721/155006.585:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:50:06.585] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Um dispositivo conectado ao sistema nÒo estß funcionando. (0x1F)[17424:14808:0721/155006.588:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:50:06.589] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Um dispositivo conectado ao sistema nÒo estß funcionando. (0x1F)[17424:14808:0721/155006.599:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:50:06.599] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.*

I need the "enable-automation" so Chrome doesnt check me as a crawler.
I'm also using these options:

```
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])   
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features')       
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```